# db.create_all not creating tables in pytest-flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm self documenting a solution to `db.create_all` for anyone that has this problem. Hopefully it will help someone.

Here is a list of other threads that did not help me:

- [db.create_all() doesn't create tables defined in separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065926/db-create-all-doesnt-create-tables-defined-in-separate-file)
- [Flask SQLAlchemy db.create_all() not creating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648170/flask-sqlalchemy-db-create-all-not-creating-database)
- [Flask-SQLAlchemy create_all doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676140/flask-sqlalchemy-create-all-doesnt-work)
- [Flask_SQLAlchemy create_all() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646052/flask-sqlalchemy-create-all-doesnt-work)

I tried creating and destroying a `db` in a `conftest.py` for pytest. Alembic autogenerate was working for me but for some reason `db.create_all` was not. Importing the models before the `db.create_all` did nothing. Neither did importing the models just after `db = SQLAlchemy()` in my `__init__.py` (I was using the application factory pattern). I was also using a Declarative Base, which may be part of the problem.

Every run of pytest resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR tests/test_main.py::test_index - sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "rule" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to short-circuit Flask-SQLAlchemy's method of hanging `create_all` on the `db` object.

I followed the pattern in the actual [SQLA docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#create-a-schema):

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

So in my conftest setup and destruction instead of `db.create_all()` and `db.drop_all()`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app(TestConfig)

    with app.app_context():
        from app.models import Access, Rule, Base
        Base.metadata.drop_all(db.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(db.engine)
        print("Creating all")
        main(app)

    yield app

    with app.app_context():
        db.session.remove()
        Base.metadata.drop_all(db.engine)
        print("Dropping all")
```

This solved the problem. Tests now pass, tables created and destroyed.